# react phone input 2 onlyCountries prop not working with array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have used react-phone-input-2 library for displaying phone number fields. I have to pass selected countries only for the country codes. I am fetching iso2countrycodes from server and passing iso2CountryCodes to my Phone input component. In console I can see the country list when the component renders but the country list dropdown on screen does not update. Here is the code snippet for Phone Input:

```
const MyPhoneInput = ({ formControl, country, defaultPhoneNumber, onPhoneNumberChange, hasError, iso2CountryCodes }) => {
    console.log("In phone input", iso2CountryCodes);   
    console.log("In phone input country", country);

    return (
        <PhoneInput
            country={country}
            value={defaultPhoneNumber}
            onChange={onPhoneNumberChange}
            onlyCountries={iso2CountryCodes}
            preferredCountries={["iq", "gb"]}
            inputProps={{
                name: formControl,
                required: true,
                id: formControl
            }}
            inputClass={`${hasError ? "error" : ""}`}
            containerClass="myPhoneInput"
        />
    )

}

export default MyPhoneInput;
```

Below is code for parent component where I am passing the data to child component:

```
                    <Controller
                    control={control}
                    defaultValue=""
                    name="phoneNumber"
                    render={({ onPhoneNumberChange }) => {
                        return (
                            <MyPhoneInput formControl="phoneNumber" country="us" defaultPhoneNumber="" hasError={errors.phoneNumber} onPhoneNumberChange={onPhoneNumberChangeHandler} iso2CountryCodes={iso2CountryCodes} />
                        );
                    }}
                    rules={{ required: true }}
                />
```

Let me know if I am missing something. (I am new to react so welcome any good suggestions to optimize my code as well). Thanks.

Comment: In console I can see the country list when the component renders but the country list dropdown on screen does not update - means the dropdown is not showing those options ?

Comment: exactly the dropdown is not updating.

Comment: If possible, create a fiddle and use an object and that has the same api data and share the link here

Comment: I will try to create a fiddle and post it once i get some more time, meanwhile any suggestions on passing array as props. I think the Phone Input component is rendered before the list updates or if I can use some hook here, I have laready tried useEffect but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding a key to phoneInput component to rerender it whenever parent component changes. As per the description the issue was with react phone input2 dropdown, it was not rerendering when passing dynamic array. For changing the reference I have passed it from parent component using an object. Below is the change I have done, hope it helps someone else:
Inside useEffect hook of Parent component:

```
 const [phoneInputObj, setPhoneInputObj] = useState({});
    useEffect(()=>{
    if (iso2CountryCodes){
            let defaultCountry =  (iso2CountryCodes?.length>0? iso2CountryCodes[0]: 'us');
            let defaultCountryCode = (defaultValues.countryCode ? defaultValues.countryCode .toLowerCase(): defaultCountry);
            setPhoneInputObj({
                "iso2List": [...iso2CountryCodes],
                "randomKey":Math.random(),
                "defaultCountryCode":defaultCountryCode
            });
        }

    },[iso2CountryCodes]);
```

> Passed the PhoneInputObj as prop to PhoneInput Component from my form
> (Parent component):

```
   <MyPhoneInput formControl="phoneNumber"  defaultPhoneNumber= 
   {phoneNumberValue} hasError={errors.phoneNumber} onPhoneNumberChange= 
   {onPhoneNumberChangeHandler} phoneObj={phoneInputObj}/>
```

> Inside MyPhoneInput component

```
       <PhoneInput
country={phoneObj.defaultCountryCode}
value={defaultPhoneNumber}
onChange={onPhoneNumberChange}
onlyCountries={phoneObj.iso2List}
inputProps={{
    name: formControl,
    required: true,
    id: formControl
}}
inputClass={`${hasError ? "error" : ""}`}
containerClass="myPhoneInput"
key={phoneObj.randomKey}
```

/>